# How do I implement a default prior of cauchy(0,1) in rstanarm?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, prior, stan

What I intend to do is use a default prior on my coefficients, and then to compute Bayes Factors for those coefficients.

Rouder and Morey (2012) say: "When using the Cauchy prior, s describes the interquartile range of a priori plausible standardized slopes. We find that s = 1 is a good default, and it specifies that the interquartile range of standardized slopes is from -1 to 1."

So this is the prior I'm trying to apply, to a continuous and a binary variable. And then I am trying to compute a Bayes Factor for each predictor. Am I doing this correctly? Thanks a million in advance.

```
#Load Packages
library(rstanarm)
library(bayestestR)

#Create Data
d <- data.frame(ppt = as.factor(rep(1:10, 10)), item =as.factor(rep(1:10, each = 10)), iv1 = as.factor(rep(0:1, 500)), iv2 = rnorm(1000), dv = rnorm(1000))

#Scale Continuous Predictor
d$iv2 <- scale(d$iv2)

#Create Prior
fixed_prior <- cauchy(0, 1, autoscale = FALSE)

#Run Model
m <- stan_lmer(dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + (1 + iv2|ppt) + (1|item), data = d, prior = fixed_prior)

#Compute Bayes Factor
bayesfactor_parameters(m)
```

Comment: To my experience, cauchy(0, 1) seems a strong (informative). I often use cauchy(0, 5).

Comment: @TrungDung thanks! Maybe I should use a range of values. I wonder if there is a good range to use? Maybe using: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 is good?

Comment: I did run a code with several values, when I check with 1, 2, 2.5, 3, it changes parameter estimates, I then check with 5, 10, 20, it does not or very slightly. You may vary it and see what happen to your problem.

Comment: @TrungDung I think that's a good approach. I'll try it, thanks!